# UICollectionview controller to UItableview controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uitableview, uicollectionview

hi I have a uicollectionview controller with two buttons ,when i click the first button it directly opens uitableview controller(with 2 button) and when i click the second button i want uicollectionview controller to show? how can i do this in storyboard?

i tried this code inside one button but its throwing one exception like "Nib file not found"

```
 table *listview=[[table alloc]initWithNibName:@"listview" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listview animated:NO];
```

{list view is the uitableviewcontroller name ,i assigned this name on uitableviewcontroller title property in right panel of xcode}

Comment: As a matter of style please name your classes with a capital.(This could just be me being crazy) Check that your spelling the xibs name right.

Comment: @BooRanger:ok.,Do you know the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Story board identifier for moving from uicollectionviewcontroller to uitableviewcontroller

```
 table *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"list"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

"Nib file not found" error makes me reckon that you haven't spelled the .xib's name correctly.

Lets say you have your controller you want to push to.

```
TableViewController.h
TableViewController.m
```

And a corresponding xib thats linked with TableViewController.h. (view, IBOutlets, etc).

```
TableView.xib
```

Now in your main ViewController we push to TableViewController

```
TableViewController *controller = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Hope this helps.

BooRanger